# GNU plots only the first of two plots

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a line plot and an error bar plot on one graph. I've found numerous examples on the Internet, so I would assume this is supposed to be trivial. However, I am having trouble tackling this. Essentially, I have a file `plot.dat` which contains:

```
set title "name" font "Helvetica, 20"
  set xlabel "xname" font "Helvetica, 20"
  set ylabel "yname" font "Helvetica, 20"
  set xrange [    0.00000: 100.00000]
  plot '-' u 1:2 with lines, '-' u 1:2:3 with yerrorbars
     1.00000        13787.5        318.595    
     3.00000        33561.5        349.861    
     5.00000        52866.6        412.335    
     7.00000        71501.0        469.513    
     9.00000        90352.7        522.629    
     11.0000        109163.        571.996    
     13.0000        127642.        617.996    
     15.0000        147510.        661.706    
     17.0000        166395.        701.951    
     19.0000        185247.        739.308    
     21.0000        203929.        774.973    
     23.0000        223604.        811.215    
     25.0000        245035.        845.310    
     27.0000        267404.        881.029    
     29.0000        293466.        920.162    
     31.0000        321489.        957.751    
     33.0000        361064.        1005.69    
     35.0000        413496.        1065.30    
     37.0000        510098.        1161.29    
     39.0000        765350.        1365.36    
     41.0000        348426.        953.718    
     43.0000        43834.8        351.409    
 e
```

I plot this by using `load 'plot.dat'`. I'm looking to have a plot where I see the errorbars and the points are connected with a line. However, what I get is a line plot with no error bars and a warning message:

```
"plot.dat", line 55: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

It's as if half of the plotting works and the other half doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the content plot.dat? Maybe a minimal version with only maybe ten points that  should be all valid but still reproduces the error.

Comment: @Aziuth I edited the post to include a bit more data. It has the same error for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you refer to the pseudo-file '-' it reads from the input stream.  You only have one copy of the data in the input stream. The first plot consumes it, leaving no data for the second plot.  You either need to provide two copies of the data in the input stream or place it somewhere that can be read from multiple times.  I.e either in a file or in a data block.  The datablock solution is shown below:

```
$DATA << EOD
     1.00000        13787.5        318.595    
     3.00000        33561.5        349.861    
     5.00000        52866.6        412.335    
     7.00000        71501.0        469.513    
     9.00000        90352.7        522.629    
     11.0000        109163.        571.996    
     13.0000        127642.        617.996    
     15.0000        147510.        661.706    
     17.0000        166395.        701.951    
     19.0000        185247.        739.308    
     21.0000        203929.        774.973    
     23.0000        223604.        811.215    
     25.0000        245035.        845.310    
     27.0000        267404.        881.029    
     29.0000        293466.        920.162    
     31.0000        321489.        957.751    
     33.0000        361064.        1005.69    
     35.0000        413496.        1065.30    
     37.0000        510098.        1161.29    
     39.0000        765350.        1365.36    
     41.0000        348426.        953.718    
     43.0000        43834.8        351.409    
EOD

plot $DATA u 1:2 with lines, $DATA u 1:2:3 with yerrorbars
```

Comment: Hmm, I see. It's just me being clumsy with Syntax it seems. Thank you for your help!